# Update adapter items with add dynamic drawable on getview() lead to show wrong data

Tags: android, listview, adapter, threadpool

I have a custom adapter that list my items. in each Item I check database and draw some circles with colors.

As you see in code I check if `convertView==null` defines new viewHolder and draw my items. but when I scroll listview very fast every drawn data ( not title and texts) show wrongs!
How I can manage dynamic View creation without showing wrong data?!

**UPDATE**

This is my attempts:

1. I used ui-thread to update my list but the result is same and data drawing go wrong.
2. in second I try to load all data with my object so that there is no need to check db in adapter. but it problem is still remains...
3. finally I create the `HashMap<key,LinearLayout>` and cache every drawn layout with id of its item. So if it's drawn before I just load its view from my HashMap and every dynamic layout will create just once. But it still shows wrong data on fast scrolling! Really I don't know what to do next!

   @Override
       public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ```
       final ViewHolder viewHolder;
       final MenuStructureCase item = getItem(position);

           if (convertView == null) {

               viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
               convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_item, null);
               viewHolder.menu_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_title);
               viewHolder.tag_list_in_menu_linear_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tag_list_in_menu_linear_layout);
               viewHolder.menu_delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_button_delete);
               importMenuTags(viewHolder, getItem(position), viewHolder.tag_list_in_menu_linear_layout);
               convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

           } else {
               viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

           }

           viewHolder.menu_title.setText(item.getTitle());


       }
       return convertView;
   }
   ```

and this is importMenuTags():

```
   private void importMenuTags(ViewHolder viewHolder, MenuStructureCase item, LinearLayout layout) {


        List<String> tags = db.getMenuTags(item.getTitle());  //this present list of string that contain my tags

        for (String tag : tags) {

            Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.color_shape);
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(each_tag_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lparams.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
            lparams.width = 50;
            lparams.height = 50;


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                rl.setBackground(drawable);
            } else {
                rl.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            }
            rl.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            layout.addView(rl);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select data from db before `adapter` initialization. So that

```
getItem(position)
```

will return already a "ready" item-object.

You shouldn't set the values to `Views` inside

```
if (convertView == null) {
    ...
}
```

This code is only for a `viewHolder` initialization. You create a new one, if `convertView` is `null` or read it as tag.
Setting of values you have to do after `viewHolder` initialization, actually where you set the title.
But in order to increase a performance, you shouldn't select the values from db on each step of `getView`. You have to have everything prepared (already selected).

Comment: when I add my drawing function outside and near to set text title unfortunately it is not work at all.

Comment: do you mean calling importMenuTags(...) after viewHolder.menu_title.setText(...)?

Comment: yes. just the position that show every thing right is there

Comment: I think problem is I create dynamic view every time. so if I manage it when its drawed not draw again i think it's gonna solve

Comment: you have to call importMenuTags() outside if (convertView == null) {...}. And you still call db in importMenuTags(). Did you update your code above?

Comment: yes, I try but in this way that you say, every time and every time view is exist or not, importMenuTags()  works and all data go wrong even without scrolling.

Comment: then your importMenuTags() returns the wrong values. You should call it anyway outside. I suppose, that the title works right, yes? try to put it in if (convertView == null) {...} and it will be cached. actually, that is the idea of convertView, that you cache the full view, you must not inflate it. But you have to set values to your views on each step

Comment: it's a bad example/solution. there is no viewHolder at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

First of all **create method inside adapter** class:

```
public void updateNewData(List<MenuStructureCase> newList){
   this.currentList = newList;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now call above method whenever you want to update **ListView**.

How to call with **object** of **CustomAdapter**:

```
mAdapter.updateNewData(YourNewListHere);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rendering of data takes times and may be that's causing the issue  when you are scrolling fast.
2. You can restirct  the scrolling ( like Gmail  : use a pull to refresh ) so that a less amount to data is processed in a list view at single time .
3. use  RecyclerView  instead of listview for better performance
4. ListView  recreates the view on scrolling .

May be you can explain more about your problem , then we can provide the inputs accordingly.

Comment: it's funny that I use Recycle Adapter in another part of my project and in onBindViewHolder() I use importMenuTags() and the problem is same in RecycleView. also I don't wanna restrict scrolling cause my data is local and not like gmail.